# Laravel app with problems on production, forcibly closes connection

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laragon

I'm posting this problem because I'm seaching everywhere and I don't find anything related to this.

I have managed to create an web-app in Laravel that connects to a user database and have a user system and several views and controllers, everything seems to be ok at developing level, but we are having some issues with the server-side,

We are using a dedicated hosting in ionos, and we made the develop of that app on Windows with Laragon program and php-artisan-serve commands, I have run several commands for clean and setup the app,

```
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan optimize
```

I have started the app with

```
npm run production
and
php artisan serve 0.0.0.0 host--xxxx
```

and everything it's working fine, but sometimes the app stops working and we have to re build and start laragon and the CMD with the commands again,

we also have communicated to the server owner and they told to us that they dont have problems and also switched to another more powerfull server,

I don't know if laravel could not be develped on windows server-side or we have to use something like Laravel Vapor or Forge

but it's strange because everything works great, on the CDM sometimes shows this error

[the image shows the cmd commands that every device that access to the url within the program is it will be loading the resorce for each view, and sometimes show that error of "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5Tw9.png)

The app connects to the database in another dedicated hosting of the same owner (IONOS)

also i have searched on the apache log and find these errors

> [Thu Apr 08 15:54:30.546241 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8708:tid
> 492] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the
> server.
>
> [Thu Apr 08 15:54:32.580416 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8752:tid
> 644] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
>
> [Thu Apr 08 15:54:33.796081 2021] [core:warn] [pid 14164:tid 460]
> AH00098: pid file
> C:/laragon/bin/apache/httpd-2.4.35-win64-VC15/logs/httpd.pid
> overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
>
> [Thu Apr 08 15:54:34.976869 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14164:tid
> 460] AH00455: Apache/2.4.35 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1b PHP/7.2.19
> configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Thu Apr 08 15:54:34.976869 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14164:tid
> 460] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: Sep 19 2018 16:08:47
>
> [Thu Apr 08 15:54:34.976869 2021] [core:notice] [pid 14164:tid 460]
> AH00094: Command line:
> 'C:\laragon\bin\apache\httpd-2.4.35-win64-VC15\bin\httpd -d
> C:/laragon/bin/apache/httpd-2.4.35-win64-VC15'
>
> [Thu Apr 08 15:54:35.008119 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14164:tid
> 460] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1636 Apache server
> interrupted...
>
> [Thu Apr 08 15:54:36.979052 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14164:tid
> 460] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the
> server.Apache server interrupted...021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid
> 1636:tid 484] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
>
> [Thu Apr 08 15:54:36.994676 2021] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 1636:tid
> 1136] (OS 10038)Se intentó realizar una operación en un elemento que
> no es un socket.  : AH00332: winnt_accept: getsockname error on
> listening socket, is IPv6 available?
>
> [Thu Apr 08 15:54:39.005041 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1636:tid
> 484] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
>
> [Thu Apr 08 15:54:39.051917 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 14164:tid
> 460] AH00430: Parent: Child process 1636 exited successfully. Apache
> server interrupted...
>
> [Thu Apr 08 15:54:42.543039 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10168:tid
> 632] AH00455: Apache/2.4.35 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1b PHP/7.2.19
> configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Thu Apr 08 15:54:42.543039 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10168:tid
> 632] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: Sep 19 2018 16:08:47
>
> [Thu Apr 08 15:54:42.543039 2021] [core:notice] [pid 10168:tid 632]
> AH00094: Command line:
> 'C:\laragon\bin\apache\httpd-2.4.35-win64-VC15\bin\httpd -d
> C:/laragon/bin/apache/httpd-2.4.35-win64-VC15'
>
> [Thu Apr 08 15:54:42.574292 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10168:tid
> 632] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 9900 Apache server
> interrupted...
>
> [Thu Apr 08 15:54:44.374117 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10168:tid
> 632] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the
> server.
>
> Apache server interrupted... 021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9900:tid
> 568] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
>
> [Thu Apr 08 15:54:44.389745 2021] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 9900:tid
> 1128] (OS 10038)Se intentó realizar una operación en un elemento que
> no es un socket.  : AH00332: winnt_accept: getsockname error on
> listening socket, is IPv6 available?
>
> [Thu Apr 08 15:54:46.403265 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9900:tid
> 568] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
>
> [Thu Apr 08 15:54:46.450145 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10168:tid
> 632] AH00430: Parent: Child process 9900 exited successfully.

I don't know what could be the problem but i'm hearing any solutions that you could say to me

Answer (score 0):

doesnt php artisan serve quit when u quit the console?

php artisan serve using php built in server which good for testing, but ofc not for production
https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

try to using webserver which intended for prodcution, either apache, or nginx etc